# Restore video count on user page

Tags: youtube

On the user page you used to see a total count of their videos, example page

[`youtube.com/svnpenn`](http://youtube.com/svnpenn)

Example string

```
274 videos
```

Today I noticed that Google has forced a new layout. This new layout for the user page no longer features video count, and I see no way to add it. Can it be added back?

> [image: Picture of problem]

Comment: If you only need to see the count, just go to any of the videos and  look [next to the user’s name](http://i.stack.imgur.com/ubLwW.png).